# Escape hyphen when reading multiple dataframes at once in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can't seem to find any documentation on this in pyspark's docs.
I am trying to read multiple parquets at once, like this:

```
df = sqlContext.read.option("basePath", "/some/path")\
                    .load("/some/path/date=[2018-01-01, 2018-01-02]")
```

And receive the following exception

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 11
E   date=[2018-01-01,2018-01-02]
```

I tried replacing the hyphen with `\-`, but then I just receive a file not found exception.

I would appreciate help on that

Comment: What are the names of the files you are trying to read?

Comment: `/some/path/date=2018-01-01/` and `some/path/date=2018-01-02`

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the `-` is not your issue. You can not specify multiple dates in a list like that. If you'd like to read multiple files, you have a few options.

**Option 1**: Use `*` as a wildcard:

```python
df = sqlContext.read.option("basePath", "/some/path").load("/some/path/date=2018-01-0*")
```

But this will also read any files named `/some/path/data=2018-01-03` through `/some/path/data=2018-01-09`.

**Option 2**: Read each file individually and union the results

```python
dates = ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-02"]
df = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.union(b), 
    [
        sqlContext.read.option("basePath", "/some/path").load(
            "/some/path/date={d}".format(d=d)
        ) for d in dates
    ]
)
```